# Zend 1, identical validator without required

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can i set the identical validator on a field without making it a required field in Zendframework 1 + allow the check of empty value.

here is the code

```
     $this->addElement('password', 'password', array(            
        'label' => 'password',
         'required' => false            
        ),
    ));
    $this->addElement('password', 'confirm', array(
        'label' => 'confirm',
        'required' => false,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'validator' => 'Identical',
                'options' => array(
                    'token' => 'password'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

If the confirm element is set to 'required'=>false, the identical validator doesn't work if the value is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Identical validator without `required` because in the `isValid()` method of `Zend_Form_Element` there is :

```
    if ((('' === $value) || (null === $value))
        && !$this->isRequired()
        && $this->getAllowEmpty()
    ) {
        return true;
    }
```

and `Zend_Form_Element_Password` is an instance of `Zend_Form_Element`. 

I think you have 3 possibilities:

1. Add `required` option in your `confirm` element, but you have a specific message required
2. Add `allowEmpty` option to false in your `confirm` element like this : `'allowEmpty' => false,` instead of `'required' => false,`
3. Create your own validator like the Cully Larson's answer. An other example it's the `example #3` of the documentation about [Writing validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html). Otherwise, you can find more on the web. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own validator for password confirmation:

```
class MyLib_Validate_PasswordConfirmation extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const PASSWORD_MISMATACH = 'passwordMismatch';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::PASSWORD_MISMATCH => 'This value does not match the confirmation value.'
    );

    /**
     * Requires that 'password_confirm' be set in $context.
     */
    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        $value = (string) $value;
        $this->_setValue($value);

        if (is_array($context)) {
            if (isset($context['password_confirm'])
                && ($value == $context['password_confirm']))
            {
                return true;
            }
        } elseif (is_string($context) && ($value == $context)) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->_error(self::PASSWORD_MISMATCH);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you mean that it is not possible to do this using zend identical validator??

Comment: @user3584625 Good question.  I don't really know, so my answer may or may not be useful  :)  I wrote this a long time ago, and possibly had some good reason for writing it (maybe the same problem you're running in to).  Though, of course, I could have been inexperienced with Zend Framework, and this was the first working solution I found.  Who's to know?